# JS and text encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I have a text file with accented characters like é. I used File Encoding Checker, it appears that the file is encoded as windows-1252.
I read the file with the following JS and node.js code:

```
fs.readFile('frenchVerbsList.txt','utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("ERROR here!: " + err);
    }
    frenchWords = data.split('\r\n');
    console.log(frenchWords);
});
```

The output from the console.log statement shows a question mark instead of the accented characters.
What has happened?

Comment: The file probably isn't UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Can you provide the file?

Answer (score 1):

Node only supports some [encodings](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L315) and `windows-1252` is not part of it. You need to convert the encoding with, for example, [encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding) to, for example, `utf-8`.

**Similar to this, but haven't tested**

```
var encoding = require("encoding");

fs.readFile('frenchVerbsList.txt', function(err, text) {
    if (err) return console.log("ERROR here!: " + err);

    var resultBuffer = encoding.convert(text, 'utf8', 'windows1252');
    frenchWords = resultBuffer.toString().split('\r\n');

    console.log(frenchWords);
})
```

Comment: It certainly looks good, and I duly installed the "encoding" module to this project's directory.  However it didn't change the output.  Then I used Notepad++ to convert the french file to utf-8, this produced correct output. Thanks for the info about the "encoding" module though, it led me in the right direction :-)